# git status command not working - under untracked files

Tags: github

I wanted to add my files onto Github so I went on Github website and I created a new repo. Then back on the terminal, before doing anything else, I first checked git status and that's what it came up:

```bash
$ git status

warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied

On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:

(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

    .bash_history

    .gitconfig

    .ipython/

    .minttyrc

    .vscode/

    AppData/

    Downloads/

    DscSignerApp/

    DscSignerAppLogs/

    Favorites/

    IntelGraphicsProfiles/

    Links/

    Music/

    NTUSER.DAT

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f17-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f17-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f17-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f17-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TxR.blf

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f18-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TM.blf

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f18-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms

    NTUSER.DAT{a2332f18-cdbf-11ec-8680-002248483d79}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms

    OneDrive/

    PKIServer.log

    PKIServer/

    Saved Games/

    Searches/

    TrustPkiServer.bat

    ntuser.dat.LOG1

    ntuser.dat.LOG2

    ntuser.ini

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I also tried to follow the steps following the answer in another stackoverflow topic but didn't work out.

Comment: Do you have your _entire_ home directory as a git repository?

Comment: What makes you say that `git status` is not working? You haven't mentioned what you expected to happen, and how that's different from what actually happened.

Comment: Git needs read/write access to the folders where your code sits on your workstation, otherwise it won't be able to track the changes (or replicate them when you switch from one branch to another).

That's what the first messages are complaining about. You should first fix that and retry.

And as Brian said, you should only put in your git repository the folders with the files you want to track, not the entirety of your personal folder (unless that's what you intend to do, but it's a terrible idea, particularly on Github, for privacy reasons)

Answer (score -1):

It says you don't have permission to read it. To get it, you need to request it manually:

`chmod -R 777 name_of_root_folder`.

This will change the permissions to 'allow everything and everyone'

Comment: I am learning how to use git and I was following  CodeWithHarry (https://youtu.be/gwWKnnCMQ5c) video. I'm just doing what he's doing and I even tried what you said, it is not working.

Comment: `chmod 777` is almost always a terrible idea